# handleTurnEventForMatch:didBecomeActive: not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, game-center, gamekit

I've faced some strange issue in multiplayer game.

The method

```
(void)handleTurnEventForMatch:(GKTurnBasedMatch *)`match `didBecomeActive:(BOOL)didBecomeActive
```

should receive a turn from other player.

But its work is inconsistent - it receives a tour without any regularity.

1 I use real devices for testing.

2 In `Itunesconnect` everything is enabled, versions are correct.

3 `[GKTurnBasedEventHandler sharedTurnBasedEventHandler].delegate` is not emppty.

And turns are received from time to time, randomly.

Could anybody help me?

Comment: Game center invitations are not working this days, I dont know what´s going on with game center SandBox server. I hope that your issue it is coming becuase of that.